# How to get SMS-C host and Port for jasmine sms gateway

Tags: jasmine, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to implement an sms gateway using Jasmine, i understand the setup and installation what i dont understand is the smpp server use to send messages. Does this refer to the web host server where jasmine is installed?

Comment: I am also looking for the same, Can someone explain me what is SMS-C means and can we get it

Answer (score 1):

First, sms-c stand Short Message Service Center which is mobile service provider stuffs related. Yes, of course. When install Jasmine on your server, you have smpp service host on port 2775 where your smpp client can connect to.